# Passing msbuild Parameter in Build.proj

Tags: .net, command-line, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I am building a dotnet project via this command line:

```
${msbuild} /m /t:Rebuild;Package /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=${WORKSPACE}/target build.proj
```

What I intend to do is pass all parameter flags in build.proj and then msbuild to get them during build time. Is that even possible and how?

Intention:

```
${msbuild}  build.proj
```

and the parameters:

```
/m /t:Rebuild;Package /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=${WORKSPACE}/target
```

**will go in build.proj**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Since you want to include moving the `/m` from the command line into `build.proj`, you will need to use [the `MSBuild` task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) in `build.proj`. (So, yes, the `msbuild.exe` process that you create from the command line will in turn execute another `msbuild.exe` process.)

```
<MSBuild
    Projects="PATH TO PROJECT FILE"
    Targets="Rebuild;Package"
    BuildInParallel="true"
    Properties="Configuration=Release;OutputPath=PATH TO OUTPUT FOLDER">
</MSBuild>
```

By the way, as long as the `Target` element that you wrap that task in is the only `Target` in `build.proj`, your `${msbuild}  build.proj` command line will execute that `Target` regardless of the value you put in its `Name` attribute.